# Asp.net MVC 4 redirect when user needs to update information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On any action I add code on over-ridden onActionExecuting method that check if user has all account info updated, if no, then redirect to an action/page that user cannot bypass unless they update their info.

In that page we get information via Ajax calls but since onActionExecuting is having the check, then any api call via ajax is done will be redirected to the page/action so the form user need to use to update info will be not functional because of that.

How to solve the issue ?

````
```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(
    ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Employee user = GetCurrentUser();            
        ViewBag.User = user;
        bool shouldUpdateUserInfo = false;
        if (user != null)
        {
            shouldUpdateUserInfo = user.UpdatedTime == null || NotifyUserInfoUpdateSince > user.UpdatedTime;
            if (shouldUpdateUserInfo)
            {
                var rvd = new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    { "action", "UpdateUserInfo" },
                    { "controller", "Account" },
                    { "returnUrl", Request.Url.AbsolutePath }
                };

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(rvd);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```
````

Comment: What about create an "Except condition" on the action receiving the ajax response so that it is not redirected? Something like (pseudo code): if (actionName == "AjaxActionUpdate") let the action move forward else RedirectToOtherRoute. Regards.

Comment: @dime2lo I thought about it but thought may be there is a more clean way to do it instead of doing the IF statement.